# VBA: OnSlideShowPageChange View.Exit Crashes PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to use VBA modules only to set up a continuous looping slideshow that loads in new slides after each playthrough. From a module in a first presentation, I'm able to open a presentation file and run a new slideshow. However when I test exiting a slideshow PPT crashes. Maybe since the SlideShowWindow is the object generating the OnSlideShowPageChange event, it breaks things if I try to exit the object in the event it generates? Or, maybe exiting the SlideShowWindow itself generates OnSlideShowPageChange, creating an infinite loop ... I guess I'm wondering how I can use the OnSlideShowPageChange event to exit a SlideShowWindow.View

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal TheActiveSlideShowWindow As SlideShowWindow)

    If TheActiveSlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition = 3 Then

        TheActiveSlideShowWindow.View.Exit   

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm going to re-tool things to use a class definition in an add-in, vs the more simple OnSlideShowPageChange. Perhaps this is a more modern, better way of creating the mechanism so that I can close a slideshow window without crashing.

Comment: Since OnSlideShowPageChange is automatically passed a reference to the SlideShowWindow that generates the event likely that's an issue - after the SlideShowWindow exits, the event handler mechanism can't find the original object. SlideShowNextSlide probably fires only on "next slide" so the issue won't happen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually no add-in needed, I just needed to use application events (as i conjectured), requiring a class module. Things are working now, yay!